# Does ExpressionEngine Have a Checkbox Fieldtype Custom Member Profile Fields?

Tags: checkbox, field, member, expressionengine

I like ExpressionEngine, but I'm starting to doubt its power.

For example, I'm looking for a checkbox [fieldtype](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/fieldtypes.html) for custom Member Profile Fields but I'm not finding anything.

Why aren't checkboxes a default option for custom member profile fields?

Is there is a plugin out there or a [simple hack for EE2](http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Enable_radio_buttons_and_checkboxes_for_custom_member_profile_fields/)?

Comment: Please explain further – can't really understand what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on ExpressionEngine v2.2.0.

See the list of php files which you will need  (in no particular order)...

- system/expressionengine/views/members/register.php - line 209
- system/expressionengine/views/members/edit-profile.php - line 70
- system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/members.php - lines 2988 and
  3086
- system/codeigniter/system/helpers/form_helper.php - get the function names form_radio, form_checkbox, form_multiselect
- system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/myaccount.php - line 309
- system/expressionengine/modals/member_modal.php - line 536 - use foreach on $data array to implode new field arrays.

There are probably a few more pages that need som attention, but this is enough to get going. Any new field types must be created in exp_member_fields.

Answer (score 1):

if you are asking to be able to set default values to custom channels fields, well, it's not currently possible, and there is no addon to do that.
In fact, I tried to create such extension, but I realized that it was not feasible with existing hooks.

Comment: Im looking for a checkbox in custom member fields. Custom channel field fine - Custom member field - nope.

Comment: Expression Engine doesnt allow for checkbox type custom member fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can build it by using the 'cp_js_end' to insert some js in order to add a checkbox, hide the default label and populate it dynamically from the checkbox state with text such 1 or 0, true or false...

Thats how modules such as member categories are made to support non-text fields.